# Migrating eclipse 3.x application application to eclipse 4.x

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-kepler, e4, eclipse-api

I'm working on a product which is an RCP application based on Eclipse 3.x api. Now we are trying to move it to Eclipse 4.x. We are using some internal classes in our code. I've already read the tutorial provided by Vogella about migrating to Eclipse 4.x from 3.x, but I'm still not getting how to start.

**We want to take advantage of the new Eclipse features, my main question is that we have good number of views, layouts in our old code, so what should be the approach I should follow. Also is there a way to create an application model from my older application using 3.x API.**

I'm stuck and not getting how to proceed.

Answer (score 5):

this really depends what you are trying to do. Do you just want to update your IDE? Or should the project be based on the e4 platform.

I recently updated a project from 3.x to the new IDE. This works very good, the compatibility layer does a good job and you are able to run the application with minimal changes. However if you do this, you cannot use the benefits of the e4 platform.

If you want to move your application to e4, thats more work to do. Mostly you will not want to touch all the old code, so there is a possiblity to have 3.x and e4 plugins run together in your application. Thats done with the e4 bridge and wrapper classes for old code. Most of the IDE views and editor are also still based on 3.x, so if you use them, the e4 bridge is also a good way to incorporate them.

Some information can be found here:

http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2011/06/10/how-to-apply-the-e4-programming-model-to-3-x/
http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/06/18/migrating-from-eclipse-3-x-to-eclipse-4-e4/

Andy

Answer (score 0):

I've read both the tutorial.But I am stucked and got too much confused as to where to start from. Basically 3 features are there
1. css styling of widgets(which i understood and did a bit of it)
2. to introduce dependency injection in my code
3. to put the application model

What approach I should follow?

Comment: see the doc on the link provided above.I think you will give you a clear idea of how to start

Answer (score 0):

This document helped me in deciding which strategy to adopt. http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/fa/17403/  for migration.Indicates clearly which strategy you should adopt based on your existing code structure.Hope it helps